# DirectX 9 вывод фона (например, квадрата 200x200) с указанием прозрачности С++

Tags: c++, directx

Здравствуйте. Я пытаюсь сделать фон указанного размера посредством оверлея DirectX9 в С++, предположим, что это квадрат 200х200 красного цвета. Указываю Альфу, а он все равно делает как буд-то альфа 255. Помогите, заранее благодарю
Коды, которые я пробовал:

```
void CRender::BoxFilled(float x, float y, float w, float h, DWORD color)
{
    vertex V[4];

    V[0].color = V[1].color = V[2].color = V[3].color = color;

    V[0].z = V[1].z = V[2].z = V[3].z = 0;
    V[0].rhw = V[1].rhw = V[2].rhw = V[3].rhw = 0;

    V[0].x = x;
    V[0].y = y;
    V[1].x = x + w;
    V[1].y = y;
    V[2].x = x + w;
    V[2].y = y + h;
    V[3].x = x;
    V[3].y = y + h;

    unsigned short indexes[] = { 0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3 };

    m_pD3dDev->CreateVertexBuffer(4 * sizeof(vertex), D3DUSAGE_WRITEONLY, D3DFVF_XYZRHW | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &g_pVB, NULL);
    m_pD3dDev->CreateIndexBuffer(2 * sizeof(short), D3DUSAGE_WRITEONLY, D3DFMT_INDEX16, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &g_pIB, NULL);

    VOID* pVertices;
    g_pVB->Lock(0, sizeof(V), (void**)&pVertices, 0);
    memcpy(pVertices, V, sizeof(V));
    g_pVB->Unlock();

    VOID* pIndex;
    g_pIB->Lock(0, sizeof(indexes), (void**)&pIndex, 0);
    memcpy(pIndex, indexes, sizeof(indexes));
    g_pIB->Unlock();

    m_pD3dDev->SetTexture(0, NULL);
    m_pD3dDev->SetPixelShader(NULL);
    m_pD3dDev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHABLENDENABLE, TRUE);
    m_pD3dDev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_SRCBLEND, D3DBLEND_SRCALPHA);
    m_pD3dDev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_DESTBLEND, D3DBLEND_INVSRCALPHA);

    m_pD3dDev->SetStreamSource(0, g_pVB, 0, sizeof(vertex));
    m_pD3dDev->SetFVF(D3DFVF_XYZRHW | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE);
    m_pD3dDev->SetIndices(g_pIB);

    m_pD3dDev->DrawIndexedPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2);

    g_pVB->Release();
    g_pIB->Release();
}
```

и

```
void fillrgba(int x, int y, int w, int h, DWORD color)
{
    D3DXVECTOR2 vLine[2];

    pLine->SetWidth(w);
    pLine->SetAntialias(false);
    pLine->SetGLLines(true);

    vLine[0].x = x + w / 2;
    vLine[0].y = y;
    vLine[1].x = x + w / 2;
    vLine[1].y = y + h;

    pLine->Begin();
    pLine->Draw(vLine, 2, color);
    pLine->End();
}
```

Ни один из них не ставит указанную альфу, пробовал ставить красный, например такой, но альфа все равно 255 - `D3DCOLOR redtz = D3DCOLOR_RGBA(255, 0, 0, 100);` Заранее еще раз благодарю

Comment: Не легче движок использовать?

Comment: Нет, я не делаю игру, я делаю оверлей DirectX на другую игру.